# What problems can arise from purchasing Windows 10 from another country/region?

Tags: windows-10

I am considering buying a Windows 10 Pro online via Microsoft store.

Currently, I am living in Japan so I get automatically redirected to the store's Japanese page.
I am surprised to see the 27,864 JPY price which is way and above 199.99 USD.
After a little checking, I found that Windows licenses from countries outside the US are usually more expensive.

Why is this the case?
Coming from Japan, is it okay for me to buy from the US page?
If yes, is there any reason for anyone from other countries to not purchase from the US page?

Comment: I am also living in Japan and thinking about buying from US store (28,000 yen vs 199.99 USD). How did it go for you? did you buy it from US store?

Comment: Ended up buying from the country of issue of my credit card (so yeah, more expensive). IIRC, if buying from US, you need to provide a US address -- w/c I don't have.

Comment: I tried to use US address but it did not work because my credit card is issued in Japan (PayPal did not work either). So ended up buying from Amazon(.)com (even lower price than Microsoft Store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

My first guess would be that customer support for other locales is significantly more expensive for Microsoft than it is in the US.  You have to keep in mind that MS is a US company at it's heart, and most of their employees are here in the US.

Local taxes and fees probably also come into play, but I doubt that they're that much of an issue.

> Coming from Japan, is it okay for me to buy from the US page?

Probably, though you might get odd questions from your bank if you don't do stuff like this regularly (the transaction will be routed differently than it would if you purchased through the Japanese page).  The caveat to this is that there may be some special fees involved because you're in Japan that would be missed if you buy from the US page.

Also, purchasing through the US page will get you English as the default language, purchasing through the Japanese storefront will get you Japanese as the default language.

> If yes, is there any reason for anyone from other countries to not purchase from the US page?

Well, to start with, the *installer* is in the correct (for a nominal definition of correct) language for the locale that the OS is being sold in.  Similarly, the default language that gets installed is also whatever the dominant local language is.  In most parts of the world, it's pretty unusual for people to be comfortable enough speaking English to want to use it as a default language on their computer (keep in mind that there are more than three times as many people who speak English as a second language than speak it natively), and many people eoither don't know how to switch the default system language or don't want to have to deal with doing so.

Additionally, as mentioned above, local taxes and fees have to be handled, or you run the risk of getting in legal trouble.

Comment: In summary, as long as I'm okay with the OS being English (w/c is what I wanted in the first place), there should be problem with purchasing from the US page. Is that right?

Comment: @libzz Pretty much yes.